SQL Server 2022 Express Instance that is both Named and Default - How did I do this?
I installed a new instance of SQL Server 2022 Express and I selected Named Instance during the installation and gave it a name. A default instance was already installed on this server.
Afterwards everything appeared normal, the service in Windows shows the name SQL Server (SQL2022EXPRESS) indicating that it is a named instance rather than a default instance.
I could connect to the server by SERVERNAME\SQL2022EXPRESS in Studio from the local host.
When it got strange is when I tried to connect via Studio from another station. Here it said it could not connect to SERVERNAME\SQL2022EXPRESS and after much troubleshooting I found that I could only connect to my new instance via just SERVERNAME.
SERVERNAME should only connect to the default instance (which is currently a disabled service)
On the localhost, if I connect to both SERVERNAME\SQL2022EXPRESS and SERVERNAME in Studio and I create a database on the named instance, it shows up on the default instance as well showing that my single newly installed instance is acting as both.
I have a single engine running that is acting as both a named and default instance all in one, yet only responding as a default instance for network connections, and listing itself as a named instance in Windows Services.
SQL Server Browser is disabled as is default.
I can not find any article explaining how this is possible. What is this configuration called and how did it become like this?
I tried searching the internet for any possibility to have an instance installed that is both a default and a named instance in one and nothing like this appears to exist. You can not be both. I verified that a named instance should only respond to it's name with network connections IE: SERVERNAME\NAME
What I am reading online does not match up with what I am experiencing.



You said that there's a default instance on the host, right? So likely SERVERNAME is connecting to that, not SERVERNAME\SQL2022EXPRESS. If the browser is disabled then passing a name won't work, as the name can't be mapped to a port. Otherwise SERVERNAME\SQL2022EXPRESS is running on port 1433, which is allowed, and without a name, the default port is used.

It is impossible that I am connecting to the original default instance because the service SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) is disabled and if I connect to the named instance and create a database, that database immediately shows up on the default instance proving that they are both the same instance. There is only 1 SQL server service running on the operating system.

So what port is SQL2022EXPRESS running on?

The new service is running on port 1433, is that what causes it to respond by machine name alone? I read online that only default instances respond to the machine name.

"The new service is running on port 1433" As I stated: "Otherwise SERVERNAME\SQL2022EXPRESS is running on port 1433, which is allowed, and without a name, the default port is used." SERVERNAME means connect to SERVERNAME with the default port, so if you have a named instance running on the default port (1433), that connection will work without the instance name.

Oh wow! So that is how it responds as a default instance. I had no idea. After getting a connection failure on install I checked what port the original instance was using and set it to the same port, so that the routing would go through with however IT had their network configured. Did not know it would change the way it responds as a named instance though. Thank you, I guess that explains it! We don't need both instances so I can continue using port 1433

If you don't need both, why not uninstall the other instance(s)?

Looks like you have four instances, one of which is the default instance. You shouldn't set a named instance to 1433, because the default instance wants to use it. This whole setup is just confusion waiting to happen. Set the named instances to other static ports, and uninstall what you don't need.

Yes, it was a last minute situation on Friday. IT reached out stating they had converted their default instance from Express to Standard by accident and was not licensed for Standard. They tried to go back and Microsoft rejects going from Standard back to Express. So a new named instance was installed and the databases were migrated. Now we can work on uninstalling the original instance and I do not know why they have the other two instances yet. The whole thing would have been a lot easier if Microsoft would have just allowed them to switch back to Express.

You can only upgrade "upwards" on all editions, @Chad . The only ones that are "kind of" downwards are Evaluation and Developer to Standard/Web. If you're on Enterprise, you can't downgrade to Standard either. In truth, it seems like the members of IT that did this shouldn't be playing with the SQL Server(s); it seems that they don't know what they are doing. They should be leaving those jobs to your DBA(s) (who also should be getting the last ~18 months of security patches and bug fixes installed on your instance(s)).

Yes it was a situation where I was helping them out since I have been working with SQL since 1999. First time I have had this occur though, but with the network failure and needing to switch to a port I knew was being routed correctly in a pinch was what caused all the confusion it seems.

Best to uninstall everything and start again. Just restore a backup of master onto a new installation of Express, then restore other DBs. You do have backups, right? Right? Agreed you need to update these instances, there are major security and bugfixes you are missing.
